# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 5

Tags: java, postgresql

I am developing my company project.

I have 2 tables. And I connected to this tables with OneToMany - ManyToOne relation.
I am using postgreSql.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<TblAgentParameters> tblAgentParameters;


@JoinColumn(name = "TBL_AGENT_PROPERTY_PARAMETERS_ID")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private TblAgentPropertyParameters tblAgentPropertyParametersList;
```

But i get this error.

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 5
Exception Details:
Location:
com/karcin/template/persistence/entities/TblAgentPropertyParameters.class$(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; @0: aload_0
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0x0000000: 2ab8 00ef b04c bb00 f159 2bb6 00f6 b700
0x0000010: f8bf
Exception Handler Table:
bci [0, 5] => handler: 5

```
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)[:1.8.0_271]
    at com.karcin.template.persistence.entities.TblAgentParameters.class$(TblAgentParameters.java)[79:karcin-template-persistence:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.karcin.template.persistence.entities.TblAgentParameters.<clinit>(TblAgentParameters.java)[79:karcin-template-persistence:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)[:1.8.0_271]
    at com.karcin.template.web.controllers.ApiController.getEntityClass(ApiController.java:154)[82:karcin-template-web:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.karcin.template.web.controllers.ApiController.test(ApiController.java:101)[82:karcin-template-web:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_271]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_271]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_271]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)[144:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)[144:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-web:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)[146:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-webmvc:3.2.18.RELEASE_1]
    ... 27 more
```

How can i this fix.?

Comment: It looks like the version of Spring you're using doesn't match the requirements for the JVM. The right answer is probably to update Spring.

Comment: Thanks your response. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something generated bytecode. That something is either [A] bugged, and messed up here, producing an invalid class file, or [B] is incredibly old<sup>1</sup>.

The fix is to, well, fix the code that messed up. If that's not your code, then file a bug with the library. If nobody maintains it anymore, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, you're out of luck.

The invalid class file is `com/karcin/template/persistence/entities/TblAgentPropertyParameters.class`.

[1] Technical detail you probably don't need to understand: Well over a decade ago java class file format was changed a little bit to add some hints about stack frames within the class file itself. The verifier is the thing that checks if a class file is 'valid', and that executing the class file cannot lead to what C coders tend to call a 'core dump' - an execution path that would break the security of the system and causes your program to be instantly hardkilled by your OS, or a security issue if the OS fails to detect it. Java promises this cannot happen, and the class verifier is a part of this. The class verifier is helped out by this stack frame registration in the class file: Verifying that this stack frame info is correct, and then verifying that the bytecode only accesses memory that it is allowed to access, is *much* simpler and faster than verifying that the bytecode only accesses memory that it is allowed to access without this information. Older class files are allowed to not have this registration, in which case the verifier will add it for you (but this takes a lot of time, which is why it's required for more modern class files). Thus, we're really still in buggy territory: Whatever made that class file put a class-file-version in that is high enough that the stack frame notes are *required*, but did not add them, and thus the verifier is rejecting the class file. Alternatively, because this is 10+ years old news, maybe these days a very modern VM is no longer capable of running very old class files because the 'figure out the stack frame' code has been removed at this point. If this is the case, downgrading back to JDK8 might work, but you really need to address this; you're running code that's 10+ years out of date.

Comment: Thank you for your response. (((: I am very happy this response. (: Thanks.